# Access different webservices endpoints through a client code

Tags: java, web-services

This is my first interaction with web services.

I have been given different endpoints of a web service.

like this -

```
http://url.to.access.web.service:8080/webserv/devgame
http://url.to.access.web.service:8080/webserv/qagame
http://url.to.access.web.service:8080/webserv/livegame
```

On my jsp code, I have a select drop down.

```
<select id="envSelector" onChange="editFn()">
  <option value="0">Select An Environment.</option>
  <option value="1">DEV</option>
  <option value="2">QA</option>
  <option value="3">LIVE</option>
</select>
```

Now depending on the value selected from the drop down, I have to hit the respective web service.

I know that in the client code, we can give the wsdl location in the @WebServiceRef annotation.

But I am not sure how to handle it in this situation. Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: Your JSP would not be calling the webservice directly (unless you're a glutton for punishment). The JSP should call a servlet which would then call the webservice

Comment: That is correct... so once I am in my servlet code, how to handle dynamic endpoint urls? I understand if it is static, we can simply put it in the `@WebServiceRef` annotation... not sure how to handle this dynamically